# Do any countries other than Azerbaijan have education requirements for a national elected office?

Tags: international, comparative-politics, election-requirements

While researching an answer for another question, I discovered that the constitution of Azerbaijan requires a presidential candidate to have a university degree. This seemed unique to me.

What other national elected offices require a certain level of education?

Within this question I am interested in elected offices, but not those specific to technical professions. For example, if a city somewhere elects their building inspector I am not interested (because it is obviously a requirement of their profession).

Comment: Do you count judges, attorney generals, etc. as "technical professions?"

Comment: I hadn't thought of them, but I am open to that as an answer.

Comment: I think that is very broad. There are many countries in the world, almost all of them have various degrees of elected public offices. Would you consider narrowing down a little?

Comment: As it's been a week now and we haven't had a flood of answers, I'm not sure that Too Broad is the right problem.  For all we know, the Azerbaijan president is the only one.

Comment: Kind of related to certain fictional countries that require military service to be a citizen.

Comment: There is a split in jurisdictions that have elected coroners between those that require educational backgrounds and those that do not. Some judicial posts require a law degree and others do not (even within the same jurisdiction). Canadian Senate membership requires you to not be a bankrupt and to own real property.

Comment: The fact that someone hasn't come up with an answer doesn't mean that it is too broad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm aware of a couple of other examples of countries which have written into their constitution explicit education requirements governing the eligibility of presidential candidates; Turkey & the Philippines. Turkey requires candidates to have completed higher education, while the Philippines has a slightly lower barrier of requiring candidates to be literate.

In addition, the Algerian Parliament [amended](https://www.aa.com.tr/en/africa/algerian-parliament-passes-electoral-bill/1583149) their election law in September 2019, introducing the "requirement for presidential candidates to have university degrees".

Article 101 of the [Constitution of the Republic of Turkey](https://global.tbmm.gov.tr/docs/constitution_en.pdf):

> The President of the Republic shall be elected directly by the public
> from among Turkish citizens over forty years of age who are eligible
> to be a deputy and have **completed higher education**.

[Article VII](https://www.officialgazette.gov.ph/constitutions/1987-constitution/#article-vii), Section 2 of the Constitution of the Republic of the Philippines:

> No person may be elected President unless he is a natural-born citizen
> of the Philippines, a registered voter, **able to read and write**, at
> least forty years of age on the day of the election, and a resident of
> the Philippines for at least ten years immediately preceding such
> election.

Comment: +1 for "slightly lower".  As someone with a graduate degree, I can confirm the barrier is only "slightly".